# Make buttons in v-card-actions responsive

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a `v-card` with three buttons (`v-btn`) in `v-card-actions` and each button has a long text on it. That's mostly no problem, but when viewed on a small screen these buttons aren't responsive, they are still aligned from left to right instead top to bottom and therefor the rightmost button is cut:

[image: screenshot with cropped button]

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-card>
      <v-card-title>
        Foo!
      </v-card-title>
      <v-card-text>
        Bar!
      </v-card-text>
      <v-card-actions>
        <v-btn>VeryLongText</v-btn>
        <v-btn>SpamSpamSpam</v-btn>
        <v-btn>Wrzlbrnft</v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

JS:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
  })
})
```

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/ocasoprotal/pen/QWwpQzz)

In my current situation I can circumvent this by using `small`, e.g. `<v-btn small>Verylongtext</v-btn>`, but I want to know how to make this fully responsive.

Vue version: 2.6.10
Vuetify: 2.1.14

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whats about using a grid?

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-card>
      <v-card-title>
        Foo!
      </v-card-title>
      <v-card-text>
        Bar!
      </v-card-text>
      <v-card-actions>
        <v-container>
          <v-row dense>
            <v-col><v-btn class="button__full">VeryLongText</v-btn></v-col>
            <v-col><v-btn class="button__full">SpamSpamSpam</v-btn></v-col>
            <v-col><v-btn class="button__full">Wrzlbrnft</v-btn></v-col>
          </v-row>
        </v-container>
      </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/rohi7787/pen/eYmvrOR)

Comment: This looks good on xs displays, thanks for that! For larger displays (sm and up) I had to add some conditional display properties (`class="d-none d-sm-flex"` and  `class="d-sm-none"`). But I still wonder why vuetify dosen't handle that out of the box.